# Hi, I'm trying to fill an array to compute the average. However it keeps giving an error

Tags: java

I have written the following code to get 6 numbers as input and then calculate their average:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class FinalGrade {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double[] quizzes = new double[6];
    double sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    double average;
    System.out.println("Please enter grades for quizzes:");
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        quizzes = input.nextDouble();
        while (i < 6) {
            sum = sum + quizzes[i];
            i++;
        }
        average = sum / quizzes.length;
        System.out.println("Your quizz average is :" + average);
    }
}
}
```

When I try to compile the code, I get the following error:

```
 ----jGRASP exec: javac -g FinalGrade.java

FinalGrade.java:17: error: incompatible types
         quizzes = input.nextDouble();
                                   ^
  required: double[]
  found:    double
1 error

 ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

I can see that the compiler is reporting an error on line 17 but I don't understand what the error is. Could you someone please help me fix it?

Comment: The error messages says that an expression of **`double[]` (array of doubles) is required** but a **`double` was found**. (Hint: check the *type* of `quizzes`, it's not a `double`! The code should probably *add* the double to the array.)

Comment: Please add the code which is resulting in error. Also, your updates should go into the question rather than into comments. Use the **edit** link at the bottom of your question to do that.

Comment: Please add the code in your question and not comments and make sure that you click on the {} button above the editable area to make your code look like code.

Comment: You should accept the best answer by clicking on the check mark next to it. This will remove the question from the questions stream.

Comment: I have edited the question to make the wording clearer. Please release it from the hold. The OP had asked his question in comments which is why he got an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add the index to the array:

```
quizzes[i] = input.nextDouble();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error is this line (which doesn't compile):

```
quizzes = input.nextDouble();
```

You're trying to assign a double to an array of doubles. Try this instead:

```
quizzes[i] = input.nextDouble();
```

Comment: Awesome. If you write your code in an IDE like Eclipse, it will highlight these kind of compilation errors -- it can be a really big time saver.

Comment: Also if that solved your problem, please mark it as accepted... that will help other people on SO know that the question has been answered.

Comment: It's weird that the OP accepted another solution whereas yours was the one which helped him. You have my +1.

Comment: @Chandranshu Thanks -- looks like that was his first question, he probably just doesn't know how the site works yet.

Comment: Yep, happens a lot to me too :)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the code you want:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class FinalGrade
{  
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  double [] quizzes = new double [6];
  double sum = 0;

  int i = 0;
  double average;

  System.out.println("Please enter grades for quizzes:");
  for (i=0; i<6; i++)
  {
     quizzes[i] = input.nextDouble();
     sum = sum + quizzes[i];
  }
  average = sum/quizzes.length;
  System.out.println("Your quizz average is :" + average);
}}
```

The resolution of your current error is to use `quizzes[i]=input.nextDouble()` but please read on.

The while loop within the for loop was going to mess up your sum calculation and you'd have had to ask another question just for that.